# Creating an x86/x64 nuget package without nusepc in new csproj format

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, csproj, nuget-spec

One of the drawbacks of the `nuspec` file is that you need to list you `nuget` dependencies all over again and don't you dare forget it when updating one of your dependencies. [For example here](https://github.com/DJDoena/MediaInfoHelper/blob/d50b037ba079e14849e2e618e7e6ab234e0f3f8d/MediaInfoHelper/MediaInfoHelper.nuspec).

As a test balloon I was trying to achieve the same goal with the new `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` project style.

With the help from [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179461/adding-x86-and-x64-libraries-to-nuget-package) and [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64498193/pack-multiple-platforms-into-one-package-using-dotnet-pack) I was able to generate a nuget package if it contains `x86`, `x64` **and** `AnyCPU`. But I don't want `AnyCPU`.

Because for some reason the `dotnet pack` command insists on finding the DLL in the default folder:

```
dotnet pack DoenaSoft.NugetTest\DoenaSoft.NugetTest.csproj --no-build -c=Release -o=./

error NU5026: The file '{...}\bin\Release\net472\DoenaSoft.NugetTest.dll'
to be packed was not found on disk. [{...}\DoenaSoft.NugetTest.csproj]
```

And I can't convince it that I neither want nor need a non-`x86`/`x64` library in my `nuget` pack

Build script and everything [here on Github](https://github.com/DJDoena/DoenaSoft.NugetTest/blob/main/.github/workflows/pushPackageToNugetOrg.yml)